# Jquery to slide in div in from right, and slide out old div to left of screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs that contain 2 screens of information.

```
<--    <div id="div1">    |    <--    <div id="div2">
```

I want to replicate the movement that is used in some apps. Namely #div1 is shown on screen, however when a button is clicked #div2 takes its place sliding in from the right whilst #div1 slides out to the left. A button on #div2 reverses the layout back.

I'm not a css or jquery guy but i'm pretty sure this is achievable and within my capabilities with a little advice. This could possible even be done with pure CSS.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery animate function like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="div1">
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="btn1" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <input type="button" id="btn2" value="btn2" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
width:200%;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
left:0;
}
#div1 {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
#div2 {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

and javascript:

```
$("#btn1").click(function () {
$(".wrapper").animate({
    left: "-100%"
}, 1000);
});

$("#btn2").click(function () {
$(".wrapper").animate({
    left: "0"
}, 1000);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/ZFLSy/)

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly, I mocked something up, but it's not very good and probably needs a LOT of work done to it, but it's a start:

[<kbd>Codepen</kbd>](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/kwxeh)

HTML:

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<button>Click</button>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.one{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}
.two{
  position:relative;
  top:-100px;
  right:-100%;
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.one').animate({'left':'-100%'});
  $('.two').animate({'right':'0'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (in Chrome at least):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VZ8ya/1/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page1" class="page"></div>
    <div id="page2" class="page"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightBlue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: orange;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

#page2 {
    left: 100%;
    background: lightGreen;
}

#wrapper.active #page1 {
    left: -100%;
}

#wrapper.active #page2 {
    left: 0;
}
```

---

Toggle the 'active' state any way you like:

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function() {
   $('#wrapper').toggleClass('active'); 
});
```